# O que esse trecho de código com cast faz?

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, assembly, cast

código tirado do site [Linux x86_64 execve Shellcode](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/39975/)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

unsigned char code[] = \
    "\x48\x89\xc6"                 // mov    %rax,%rsi
    "\x48\x89\xf2"                 // mov    %rsi,%rdx
    "\x49\xbc\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f" // movabs $0x68732f6e69622f,%r12
    "\x73\x68\x00"               
    "\x41\x54"                     // push   %r12
    "\x54"                         // push   %rsp
    "\x5f"                         // pop    %rdi
    "\xb0\x3b"                     // mov    $0x3b,%al
    "\x0f\x05"                     // syscall 
;

main()
{

    printf("Shellcode Length:  %d\n", (int)strlen(code));

    int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;

    ret();

}
```

o que essa linha de código esta fazendo?

```
int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isso é uma técnica para executar a função escrita em código de máquina ou outra forma onde não se sabe o nome da função, mas se sabe onde ela está.

Note que `code` é uma variável com o código de máquina montado a partir daquele código Assembly nos comentários. Como chamar isso através de C? As chamadas só podem ser através de funções. Então temos que interpretar esse *array* de bytes como se fosse uma função. C possui uma forma de se referenciar à funções de forma anônima.

Nesse caso terá uma variável chamada `ret` que é do tipo "função que retorna um inteiro". Os parenteses finais no nome da variável e o ponteiro (afinal toda função é um ponteiro para um código) é o que indica que no fundo é uma função.

O `(int(*)())` é um *cast* para fazer com que esse *array* de bytes seja convertido para uma função. Não que seja feita uma conversão mesmo, apenas será interpretado assim pelo compilador. Isso é feito para compatibilizar com o que se espera na variável.

Assim você consegue executar um código arbitrário. Ele poderia vir até de fontes externas, o que pode ser um perigo. Em alguns casos o sistema operacional pode impedir a execução de códigos arbitrários.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

```
int(*ret)()
```

É feita declaração de uma função ponteiro chamada `ret`, a função leva argumentos não especificados e retorna um inteiro.

```
(int(*)())code
```

Converte a array `code` para um ponteiro de uma função desse mesmo tipo.

Portanto converte o endereço da array `code` para um ponteiro de uma função, que, em seguida, permite que você chamá-lo e executar o código .

Tradução de:
[What does int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21951381/what-does-int-ret-intcode-mean)