# Como uma classe é organizada na memória?

Tags: classes, estrutura-de-dados, memória

Segundo esta definição do que é memória:

> Em computação, memória refere-se aos dispositivos físicos utilizados
>    para armazenar programas (sequencias de instruções) ou dados
>    (informações de estado, por exemplo) em um programa de caráter
>    temporário ou permanente para o uso em um computador ou outro
>   dispositivo eletrônico digital.
>
> [fonte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/mem%C3%B3ria/info).

Seguindo esta definição foi gerado as seguintes dúvidas que serão abordadas no final da pergunta. Abaixo segue uma classe para servir de exemplo e ilustração.

```cs
public class Pessoa
{
    //Constante
    private const string caminhoFoto = @"C:\fotos"; 

    //Propriedades 
    public string Nome { get; set; } = "";
    public int Idade { get; set; } = 0;

    public Pessoa(string nome, int idade)
    {
        Nome = nome;
        Idade = idade;
    }

    public Pessoa() { }

    //Metodos

    public List<String> Validar()
    {
        List<String> mensagemValidacao = new List<string>();
        //Metodo de "validação" para exemplificar.

        return mensagemValidacao;
    }

    public void Salvar()
    {
        //Metodo para "salvar no banco" para exemplificar.
    }
}
```

Exemplo de implementação da classe Pessoa:

```cs
Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa("Jao", 21);
pessoa.Salvar();
```

---

## Dúvidas

Seguindo a definição que está no início da pergunta, eu gostaria  que me esclarecessem as seguintes dúvidas:

1. Como é organizada na memória principal uma classe (após ser
   instaciada) e suas caracteristicas como propriedades, constantes e
   métodos?
2. Quem é responsavel por organizar os dados na memória, o compilador
   da linguagem ou o sistema operacional?

<sup>Optei por usar a linguagem C# no exemplo, mas podem citar exemplo de outras linguagens também.</sup>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## TL;DR

Na verdade, o objeto é só uma sequência de bytes equivalentes a seus **campos** de instância e é totalmente isolado do resto. A instância é só o objeto simples. O resto do que está na classe é algo separado e fica em uma área estática de forma única. O objeto (do seu exemplo), bem grosso modo, ficará assim:

```
|0A|B5|68|4F|00|00|00|00|
\-----------/\----------/
   string        int
```

Esse é o endereço (chutado) de onde fica o texto (sequencia de caracteres) e depois o número 0 como inteiro de 32 bits. Considerei que está usando arquitetura de 32 bits para saber o tamanho do ponteiro.

## Introdução

Farei algumas simplificações, inclusive os detalhes podem variar dependendo da linguagem. Vou falar sobre linguagens estaticamente tipadas, as demais podem ter uma organização mais abstrata ainda. Algumas coisas são detalhes de implementação e podem mudar ou ser um pouco diferente do que falarei.

O assunto é complexo e importante para quem quer dominar a computação de forma mais profunda. Daria para escrever um livro aqui. Recomendo fortemente seguir os *links* da resposta e procurar novas informações por conta própria para se aprofundar e entender melhor alguns conceitos. Infelizmente nem tudo que precisa de mais detalhes tem resposta aqui no site. Cabem novas perguntas.

Vou me concentrar em C#. Java é muito parecido, mas faltam nela alguns recursos que falarei. C++ é diferente em poucos pontos: não há diferença entre `struct` e `class`, a instanciação define onde alocar, o cabeçalho do objeto varia conforme o alocador usado e não tem nada que facilite o *garbage collector*, travamento e polimorfismo (a não ser que o use, mas é fora da alocação), e faltam algumas facilidades que o C# tem. Outras linguagens, como D por exemplo, funcionam de forma bem semelhante. Não será muito diferente em Rust ou Go ou ainda Pascal.

A classe após ser instanciada é o objeto. Ele só tem estado, ou seja, só terá as dados das variáveis de instância. Os comportamentos não ficam na instância, mesmo que pareça estar junto. É ilusão.

## Funcionamento do CLR

O C#, pelo menos na sua forma padrão, funciona com um *runtime* complexo que cuida do gerenciamento de memória, o [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101), controle de concorrência, segurança, entre outras coisas. Tem mais detalhes em [O que é realmente o "runtime environment"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101). O Java também, C++ possui um *runtime* muito, muito simples.

Isso vale para o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) também. Ele é um pouco diferente, mas são detalhes. Também existe o [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101) que não tem o JITter e é mais simplificado em alguns aspectos (o *runtime* do Mono pode funcionar parecido).

Entenda melhor sobre a ["interpretação" do código binário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142289/101).

O JITter pega o *bytecode* gerado pelo compilador e armazenado no que seria o executável e transforma em código nativo. Então todo código executável acaba ficando em uma parte do *heap*. Mesmo que eu fale de métodos em área estática, é um *heap* estático que é gerado em tempo de execução. Veja mais em [Como funciona a execução de uma aplicação .NET?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118694/101).

Não entrarei em detalhes sobre o *heap*, as suas 3 gerações do gerenciador de memória (*garbage collector*) e área de objetos grandes, nem do *heap* não gerenciado.

Leia [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

O CLR é responsável por toda organização da memória. Claro que ele precisa pedir permissão ao sistema operacional para começar trabalhar e alocar memória, mas a organização é basicamente dele, quando ele precisa ele pede para o SO para ajudá-lo em alguma coisa.

A organização pode ser vista aqui (imagem obtida de acordo com o *link* postado pelo Bruno Costa):

[image: Heap CLR]

O .NET Core e Native não possuem domínios de aplicação.

Tem uma [pergunta com um código C que pode ajudar entender como é criar uma função *on-the-fly*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136361/101). Após o JITter fazer seu trabalho de pós-compilação, ele gera uma sequência de bytes e armazena no *heap* estático que falei antes.

## As partes na memória

### Métodos

É um engano as pessoas imaginarem que os métodos estão junto do objeto. Na verdade os métodos são simplesmente funções e residem em uma área estática. E existe apenas **um** método para a classe, as instâncias compartilham o que está lá, não existe nenhuma razão para ter um para cada instância. Após o JITter criá-lo ele é fixo (para otimizar mais é pode ser trocado por uma versão melhorado quando o JITter perceber que ele é muito usado e tem oportunidades de fazer uma otimização mais agressiva).

Pode parecer estranho, mas todos métodos na verdade são como se fossem estáticos, usando a terminologia que em geral os programadores C# conhecem. A diferença do método declaradamente estático e o método de instância é que o de instância tem um parâmetro oculto chamado `this` que recebe o objeto a ser manipulado. Sim, o que você manipula dentro do método está apenas manipulando o objeto normal recebido como parâmetro. Mesmo quando não precisa usar o `this`, o compilador coloca para você. Falo de algo sobre isso em [Quando de fato preciso usar o operador this no Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154186/101) (não achei uma mais canônica).

As funções só possuem o código a ser executado. Os espaços para as variáveis locais das funções ficam na *stack* (uma por *thread*) e vão sendo acumuladas em pilha, como o próprio nome diz, de acordo com as chamadas. Na pilha só são colocados os valores básicos dos dados. Se for um [tipo por valor o objeto estará ali, e se for um tipo por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101) ali só terá uma referência para o objeto que estará no *heap* (em C#).

Importante notar que tipos por valor também podem ser alocados em registradores por causa de otimizações do JITter, ou no *heap* por estarem embutidos em outros objetos que estão lá.

Já escrevi mais detalhes sobre isso em [Como funciona o gerenciamento de métodos na memória em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14334/101).

Todos os métodos (`Validar()`, `Salvar()`, os construtores, inclusive os 4 métodos que não parecem existir - veja abaixo) ficam em área estática, mas em um *heap* especial. Essas áreas são abstratas, não pense em uma separação bonitinha na memória.

A propriedade declarada criará dois métodos públicos para fazer o `get` e `set` das variáveis privadas então tem 4 métodos para criar (2 para cada propriedade) que não parecem óbvios. Mais detalhes em [Nova funcionalidade do C# 6 "Auto-property initializers" é apenas um facilitador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108516/101). Ali não fala em detalhe, mas o [código CIL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138577/101) abaixo demonstra que a inicialização de os campos das propriedades se dão na construção, em um método, ações (comportamento) só podem estar dentro de métodos. Falo sobre em [Métodos e propriedades em C# - vantagens e desvantagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15467/101)

Já falei que as funções, que na verdade são métodos de instância, recebem um parâmetro `this`. Um parâmetro não deixa de ser uma variável local e ela é que guardará "o objeto". Na verdade sendo uma classe o que a variável guarda de fato é uma referência (um ponteiro) para o objeto propriamente dito. Aparentemente o foco da pergunta é sobre esse objeto, mas é importante mostrar onde vão as outras coisas "constantes".

#### Constantes

A constante `caminhoFoto` fica em área estática. Note que essa variável em específico terá um ponteiro e separadamente o objeto com a sequência de caracteres em outra parte da área estática (por ser *string*).

Constantes ou qualquer coisa que sejam plenamente definidos em tempo de compilação ficam nessa área estática do código que acabará indo para a memória. Obviamente tudo que fica nessa área nunca será modificado, daí o nome estática.

O mesmo se dá com [variáveis estáticas em geral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27776/101) (pelo menos seu valor). A diferença para uma constante é que essa última pode ser otimizada, ou seja, o seu valor pode usado nos códigos consumidores de forma direta. Pode copiar o valor, não precisa criar uma referência para ele como é comum em variáveis e nem precisa armazenar seu valor em algum lugar, não há [indireção](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection). Note que o **valor** de uma *string* de fato é o ponteiro para o texto efetivo, o texto teria que existir em algum lugar sempre.

Cuidado para não confundir constante com variável imutável. Variáveis não podem estar na área estática, nunca. Alguns objetos imutáveis até podem, é bem o caso de *strings*. Obviamente que *strings* construídas em tempo de execução não estarão nunca em área estática.

É bem comum todos os literais *string* ficarem na área estática, inclusive fazendo [*interning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).

Em C# e Java até informações relevantes sobre a classe (ou qualquer outro tipo de dados) pode ficar nessa área. Esses são os [metadados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107111/101), a tabela de polimorfismo ([*vtable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)), entre outras coisas. A resposta do Bruno Costa tem um infográfico mostrando em detalhes.

#### Objeto

A alocação geral de um tipo por referência ocorre em partes: a referência, que pode estar em vários lugares (sempre em uma variável), inclusive por ter várias referências para o mesmo objeto; e o objeto mesmo. Nem tudo o que você vê ali está junto.

Um diagrama pode ajudar entender o que vai na *stack* (o que não é o objeto em si) e o que vai no *heap* (sem considerar as gerações). Vou falar do objeto propriamente dito.

[image: Alocação CLR]

#### Cabeçalho

Quando o objeto é instanciado com a estrutura definida na classe a alocação precisa dos dados inicializados, normalmente pelo construtor, e de dados de controle interno.

Nesse objeto, que é armazenado no *heap*, costuma ter um cabeçalho. Cada linguagem vai ser de um jeito.

Tem uma [palavra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)) (tamanho de um ponteiro) que indica de qual tipo aquele objeto é (TypeHandle). Esse ponteiro é importante por uma série de razões, desde ser usado pelo gerenciamento do coletor de lixo para saber o que fazer com aquilo, até reflexão (pegar os dados do tipo) e polimorfismo (*vtable*, a tabela virtual de métodos). Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre isso aqui, o assunto vai longe.

O tipo (um objeto complexo rico em informações (conforme o infográfico da resposta do Bruno) fica armazenado em algum lugar da área estática (como dito acima), portanto tem um endereço, é esse endereço que vai ali no cabeçalho.

O C# tem mais uma palavra (*SyncBlock*) para outros controle do *garbage collector*, travamento quando há concorrência, cache de *hashcode* e outras coisas. Leia mais em [artigo em inglês](http://joeduffyblog.com/2007/06/24/clr-monitors-and-sync-blocks/).

É um pouco mais complexo que isso, mas essa é a base.

O objeto mínimo terá 12 ou 24 bytes (32/64 bits), mesmo que não existam dados nele (*empty class*). Uma [palavra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185523/101) extra é reservada para esse caso, mas se tiver dados - o comum - essa palavra é aproveitada para eles. As alocações de objetos são sempre feitas em grupos de palavras, portanto em múltiplos de 4 ou 8 bytes. Se precisar ele [faz um alinhamento (*padding*)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125057/101).

#### Dados do objeto

Depois o que vem nele é o objeto propriamente dito e variará de acordo com o que foi definido dentro da classe. O que terá ali é uma sequência simples de bytes que correspondem aos membros declarados na classe. Por isso que uma cópia, chamada bit a bit, copia todo o objeto de forma bem simples (essencialmente ele faz um `memcpy()` do C).

Para quem conhece bem C é fácil entender, já que é o equivalente a uma `struct`. Acho que já deu para entender que essas linguagens de mais alto nível só criaram novas abstrações em cima do que já existia.

Então se você tem uma `string` e um `int`, o objeto da classe exemplo na pergunta terá 8 ou 12 bytes (mas a alocação total dele será acrescida de 8 ou 16 bytes do cabeçalho).

A variável que é uma *string* ocupará o espaço de um ponteiro já que *strings* são por referência, portanto o objeto texto de verdade estará em outro lugar do *heap* (sim, haverá uma nova alocação com um objeto separado, a *string já é uma classe, embora poderá haver uma otimização a apontar para uma área estática da memória). Por isso não sei se o tamanho dele é 4 ou 8 bytes, dependerá se estiver em arquitetura 32 bits ou 64 bits.

O tipo `int` em C# sempre tem 4 bytes e é um tipo por valor, então o objeto já está ali mesmo, por que é como se fosse uma `struct` e não uma `class`.

Veja [Qual a diferença entre Struct e Class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101).

#### Campos das propriedades

O C#, nesse caso, cria membros com nomes internos que se assemelhará ao usado na propriedade (Ex.: `<Nome>k__BackingField`), na ordem que foram declaradas na classe, ou de forma reorganizada para dar melhor alinhamento na memória (juntar membros com menos que uma palavra para tentar alocá-los juntos em apenas uma palavra). Esses membros serão privados e eles serão o **estado** do objeto. Não é a propriedade, que é o conjunto desse campo privado com o par de métodos de acesso.

Quando o compilador precisa acessar uma variável privada, dentro da classe ou até do *assembly* (unidade de compilação), ele apenas calcula onde deve ser o acesso, ele não precisa saber o nome. É como nas variáveis locais, o nome existe mais para o programador entender, o compilador só precisa de endereços.

As variáveis que suportam propriedades normalmente só são acessadas indiretamente através dos seus métodos acessadores e modificadores, em tese só eles acessarão seus campos associados, mas nada impede que seja diferente internamente.

#### Acesso ao objeto

O acesso a esses campos é controlado internamente e determinado pelo compilador. Ele sempre será o endereço do objeto, que será armazenado em alguma variável da aplicação, mais o deslocamento do membro (é uma soma mesmo).

No caso, se for pegar a *string* o deslocamento é zero. Se fizermos uma analogia com um *array* é o elemento 0. Só não pode fazer a analogia por completo porque cada membro pode ter um tamanho diferente enquanto que no *array* o tamanho de todos elementos é igual.

A segunda variável de instância seria como o índice 1, então para acessá-la seria o endereço do objeto mais o tamanho do primeiro campo (4 ou 8 bytes).

## Conclusão

Não falei de muita coisa, por exemplo não falei das condições especiais dos construtores, quando tem destrutores e finalizadores. Alguma coisa pode mudar no futuro, e posso ter simplificado tanto que posso ter escorregado em alguma coisa.

É complicado acompanhar tudo isso sem ver, e entender todo o processo de uma vez parece uma loucura. Mas se pensar bem, é muito simples. Não tem uma engenhosidade tão grande quanto possa parecer, um pouquinho tem :).

[Livro recomendado](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621632).

Se quiser entender melhor [como o CLR funciona e faz tudo isso tem o fonte disponível](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr). Não é tarefa fácil :)

Se tiver interesse em conhecer o código da CIL que será gerado, pode ajudar enxergar algumas coisas que estou falando. Note que os métodos possuem informação do espaço que ele precisa reservar na *stack* que é gerenciado automaticamente pelo ambiente. O código é apenas uma representação textual (até com comentários) que um humano minimamente treinado consegue entender. Na verdade o código mesmo são apenas alguns bytes que indicam isso, os saltos dos números dos endereços entre as instruções dá uma ideia de quantos bytes cada uma ocupa.

```
.class private auto ansi '<Module>'
{
} // end of class <Module>

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit Program
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig static 
        void Main () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 22 (0x16)
        .maxstack 2
        .locals init (
            [0] class Pessoa
        )

        IL_0000: nop                  // Do nothing (No operation)
        IL_0001: ldstr "Jao"          // Push a string object for the literal string
        IL_0006: ldc.i4.s 21          // Push num onto the stack as int32, short form
        IL_0008: newobj instance void Pessoa::.ctor(string, int32) // Allocate an uninitialized object or value type and call ctor
        IL_000d: stloc.0              // Pop a value from stack into local variable 0
        IL_000e: ldloc.0              // Load local variable 0 onto stack
        IL_000f: callvirt instance void Pessoa::Salvar() // Call a method associated with an object
        IL_0014: nop                  // Do nothing (No operation)
        IL_0015: ret                  // Return from method, possibly with a value
    } // end of method Program::Main

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2072
        // Code size 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0              // Load argument 0 onto the stack
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor() // Call method indicated on the stack with arguments
        IL_0006: nop                  // Do nothing (No operation)
        IL_0007: ret                  // Return from method, possibly with a value
    } // end of method Program::.ctor

} // end of class Program

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit Pessoa
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Fields
    .field private static literal string caminhoFoto = "C:\\fotos"
    .field private string '<Nome>k__BackingField'
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableState) = (
        01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    )
    .field private int32 '<Idade>k__BackingField'
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableState) = (
        01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    )

    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig specialname 
        instance string get_Nome () cil managed 
    {
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        // Method begins at RVA 0x207b
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0              // Load argument 0 onto the stack
        IL_0001: ldfld string Pessoa::'<Nome>k__BackingField' // Push the value of field of object (or value type) obj, onto the stack
        IL_0006: ret                  // Return from method, possibly with a value
    } // end of method Pessoa::get_Nome

    .method public hidebysig specialname 
        instance void set_Nome (
            string 'value'
        ) cil managed 
    {
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2083
        // Code size 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0              // Load argument 0 onto the stack
        IL_0001: ldarg.1              // Load argument 1 onto the stack
        IL_0002: stfld string Pessoa::'<Nome>k__BackingField' // Replace the value of field of the object obj with value
        IL_0007: ret                  // Return from method, possibly with a value
    } // end of method Pessoa::set_Nome

    .method public hidebysig specialname 
        instance int32 get_Idade () cil managed 
    {
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        // Method begins at RVA 0x208c
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0              // Load argument 0 onto the stack
        IL_0001: ldfld int32 Pessoa::'<Idade>k__BackingField' // Push the value of field of object (or value type) obj, onto the stack
        IL_0006: ret                  // Return from method, possibly with a value
    } // end of method Pessoa::get_Idade

    .method public hidebysig specialname 
        instance void set_Idade (
            int32 'value'
        ) cil managed 
    {
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2094
        // Code size 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0              // Load argument 0 onto the stack
        IL_0001: ldarg.1              // Load argument 1 onto the stack
        IL_0002: stfld int32 Pessoa::'<Idade>k__BackingField' // Replace the value of field of the object obj with value
        IL_0007: ret                  // Return from method, possibly with a value
    } // end of method Pessoa::set_Idade

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor (
            string nome,
            int32 idade
        ) cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x209d
        // Code size 43 (0x2b)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0              // Load argument 0 onto the stack
        IL_0001: ldstr ""             // Push a string object for the literal string
        IL_0006: stfld string Pessoa::'<Nome>k__BackingField' // Replace the value of field of the object obj with value
        IL_000b: ldarg.0              // Load argument 0 onto the stack
        IL_000c: ldc.i4.0             // Push 0 onto the stack as int32
        IL_000d: stfld int32 Pessoa::'<Idade>k__BackingField' // Replace the value of field of the object obj with value
        IL_0012: ldarg.0              // Load argument 0 onto the stack
        IL_0013: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor() // Call method indicated on the stack with arguments
        IL_0018: nop                  // Do nothing (No operation)
        IL_0019: nop                  // Do nothing (No operation)
        IL_001a: ldarg.0              // Load argument 0 onto the stack
        IL_001b: ldarg.1              // Load argument 1 onto the stack
        IL_001c: call instance void Pessoa::set_Nome(string) // Call method indicated on the stack with arguments
        IL_0021: nop                  // Do nothing (No operation)
        IL_0022: ldarg.0              // Load argument 0 onto the stack
        IL_0023: ldarg.2              // Load argument 2 onto the stack
        IL_0024: call instance void Pessoa::set_Idade(int32) // Call method indicated on the stack with arguments
        IL_0029: nop                  // Do nothing (No operation)
        IL_002a: ret                  // Return from method, possibly with a value
    } // end of method Pessoa::.ctor

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x20c9
        // Code size 27 (0x1b)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0              // Load argument 0 onto the stack
        IL_0001: ldstr ""             // Push a string object for the literal string
        IL_0006: stfld string Pessoa::'<Nome>k__BackingField' // Replace the value of field of the object obj with value
        IL_000b: ldarg.0              // Load argument 0 onto the stack
        IL_000c: ldc.i4.0             // Push 0 onto the stack as int32
        IL_000d: stfld int32 Pessoa::'<Idade>k__BackingField' // Replace the value of field of the object obj with value
        IL_0012: ldarg.0              // Load argument 0 onto the stack
        IL_0013: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor() // Call method indicated on the stack with arguments
        IL_0018: nop                  // Do nothing (No operation)
        IL_0019: nop                  // Do nothing (No operation)
        IL_001a: ret                  // Return from method, possibly with a value
    } // end of method Pessoa::.ctor

    .method public hidebysig 
        instance class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string> Validar () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x20e8
        // Code size 13 (0xd)
        .maxstack 1
        .locals init (
            [0] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string>,
            [1] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string>
        )

        IL_0000: nop                  // Do nothing (No operation)
        IL_0001: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string>::.ctor() // Allocate an uninitialized object or value type and call ctor
        IL_0006: stloc.0              // Pop a value from stack into local variable 0
        IL_0007: ldloc.0              // Load local variable 0 onto stack
        IL_0008: stloc.1              // Pop a value from stack into local variable 1
        IL_0009: br.s IL_000b         // Branch to target, short form
        IL_000b: ldloc.1              // Load local variable 1 onto stack
        IL_000c: ret                  // Return from method, possibly with a value
    } // end of method Pessoa::Validar

    .method public hidebysig 
        instance void Salvar () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2101
        // Code size 2 (0x2)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: nop                  // Do nothing (No operation)
        IL_0001: ret                  // Return from method, possibly with a value
    } // end of method Pessoa::Salvar

    // Properties
    .property instance string Nome()
    {
        .get instance string Pessoa::get_Nome()
        .set instance void Pessoa::set_Nome(string)
    }
    .property instance int32 Idade()
    {
        .get instance int32 Pessoa::get_Idade()
        .set instance void Pessoa::set_Idade(int32)
    }

} // end of class Pessoa
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Foi um excelente *peek-view* do `CLR`.

Comment: Quer na minha pergunta quer na sua falta uma referencia obrigatória para o [ECMA](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf). Fica aqui para quem estiver interessado em ver em todo o detalhe o `CLI`

Comment: É bem útil sim.

Comment: Não entendi direito essa questão de cabeçalho do objeto. No caso o objeto tem um cabeçalho que é inicializado quando o objeto é instanciado ?

Comment: @DiegoFarias sim, todo objeto por referência tem isso antes do dado propriamente dito. Isto é usado para controle interno do *runtime*. Na verdade em qualquer plataforma precisa de um cabeçalho pelo menos para informar o tamanho do objeto. A única forma de evitar esse custo é ter arenas separadas para cada tamanho que pode alocar, o que é virtualmente impossível de alcançar em muitas situações e tem várias desvantagens. Faria uma bela bagunça na memória e destruiria a performance.

Answer (score 7):

## Quais são as zonas de memória

Para responder a esta pergunta creio que é uma boa ideia voltar ao velhinho `assembly`.

Num programa (que ultimamente consta em instruções `assembly`), existem várias zonas de memória, entre as quais:

- BSS e Data (dados não iniciados e iniciados, respetivamente, partilhados com outras aplicacoes.)
- Stack
- Heap

[Fonte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment#Data)

## Como é que estas zonas de memórias são usadas em `C#`

Em `C#` as seguinte operações resultam nas consequentes zonas de memória

- `new` de uma classe é sempre alocado no *heap*
- sempre que você chama um função, você aumenta o *stack*
- dentro das funções `new` de uma `struct` ocupa o espaço no *stack* do tamanho dessa `struct`. Enquanto `new` de uma classe ocupa apenas o tamanho de um ponteiro no *stack*

Em `C#` não existe conceito de dados não iniciados, todos os dados são iniciados com valores por omissão, tudo a 0, ou `null`, por isso o `BSS` pode não ser usado.

É simples imaginar que constantes possam ir parar à zona *Data*.

## Quais são os responsáveis por especificar as zonas de memórias e de as gerir

De certa forma pode-se dizer que não existe um único responsável por organizar os dados nestas zonas. Em vez disso pode-se dizer que cada um trata de coisas diferentes

- O programa especifica qual a quantidade de cada tipo de memória (em tempo de compilação só é importante saber a memória `Data` e `BSS`)
- O sistema operativo trata de guardar essas zonas de memórias em seccoes diferentes da memória *RAM*
- Cabe ao programa fazer gestão do *heap*

O *stack* é normalmente gerido automaticamente, em linguagens que não sejam de baixo nível (ou seja, praticamente em todas as linguagens que não o *assembly*)

## Como é que os métodos sao guardados

Em `C#` todos os tipos tem *metadata*, esta é a mesma *metadata* que pode ser obtida através da `API` de reflexão.

Dentro dessa *metadata*, existe uma tabela para os métodos virtuais, uma tabela para as implementações explicitas de Interface, nota que esta tabela contém apenas um ponteiro para os métodos e não o seu código.

O código é guardado na *dll*, no `Java` é compilado para `bytecode`enquanto no`C#` o código é compilado para `IL` (que é também um `bytecode` mas tem um formato diferente do `Java`). O `bytecode` é depois compilado para *assembly* com o compilador `JIT (just-in-time)`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808982/clr-implementation-of-virtual-method-calls-to-interface-members)

## Como é que objeto é representado em memória

Esta imagem mostra informações bastante interessantes. Pode observar que um objeto ocupa pelo menos `8 bytes` em `32 bits`, ou `16 bytes` em `64 bits`.

Isto porque todos os objetos armazenam um ponteiro que tem informação sobre os monitores (os monitores são objetos de sincronização), assim como um ponteiro para o seu tipo.

A isto acresce memória por cada membro da sua classe. Normalmente também é feito `padding` para que o processador tenha o trabalho facilitado a obter a informação da instância da memória.

## Como isto tudo se mostra no seu exemplo

Quando você cria uma instância de `Pessoa`

```
var pessoa = new Pessoa("Jao", 21);
```

Um objeto é criado com a seguinte estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já o `caminhoFoto` é armazenado na secção `Data` e não faz parte da informação do objeto.

Pode usar a imagem que tem a tabela de métodos para saber qual é a estrutura do seu tipo `Pessoa`. E como os seus métodos e interfaces estão organizados.

Comment: Um link melhor para a primeira imagem seria o seguinte https://web.archive.org/web/20150515023057/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx. Esse link tem também muita informacao relacionada ao assunto.

Comment: Ainda ficou umas coisinhas que pode dar uma interpretação errada, mas nada que a minha também não tenha. Vou apagar aqui o que não é relevante mais.

Answer (score 4):

Na memória, tudo é armazenado no formato "endereço" = "valor". Não é armazenada nenhuma informação com relação a tipo ou finalidade para aquele valor. Quem cuida da checagem da validade de cada valor (como tipagem) e validade de cada operação (como validar soma entre dois números e invalidar soma de número com caractere no caso de um compilador de uma linguagem estritamente tipada) é o compilador.

Respondendo:

1. Na memória, as variáveis serão armazenadas no formato "endereço" = "valor".
2. O sistema operacional é responsável por selecionar o local na memória e alocar o valor atribuído. O compilador é responsável por validar todas as operações do programa a ser compilado e providenciar o controle (instruções de leitura na memória para a CPU, onde especifica quantos bytes para cada tipo de dado) entre as variáveis a serem utilizadas e os endereços selecionados pelo SO em tempo de execução (dentre mil outras coisas).